# Upload Image - Post request to php script - Android

Tags: php, android, post, upload, request

I would like to upload an image by sending the image to a php script. It works fine if the internet connection is good. But sometimes it does not work. E.g. when the internet connection is slow.
So I'm looking for a way to upload the image with a slow connection. 
What can I do? The filesize is already quite small, about 40kb.
The code should try to upload the image until it is done.

**Edit:** Code for the upload:

```
public void upload(String uploadImage){
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("App", 0);
     String emailaddress = settings.getString("mailaddress", null);
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",uploadImage));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailaddress));
     try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new
            HttpPost("http://domain.de/uploadImage.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
            try {
            Thread.sleep( 10000 );
            }catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            upload(uploadImage);
     }
}
```

Comment: Plz share your code...

Comment: loop(i.e 2 0r 3 times) it until you receive success from the server.

Comment: I tried it by catching Exception. But I don't think this is the best way to handle it. Code will be added.

Comment: no why do you want to catch exception. If its exception then its some other problem

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to run your upload process in background.. you can show your progressbar while loading the operation.

```
public class UploadProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
super.onPreExecute();
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show(); 
} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
super.onProgressUpdate(values);
// Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{ 
  //Post Execute
   dialog.cancel();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

// Your operation..Dont Edit Any Views here
boolean isDataSubmitted = false;
        while (!isDataSubmitted) {
            count++;
            if (count < 2)//Count depends on you {
                try {
                   //Call your upload  method here 
                   //If its success your dataSubmitted will go true

                   isDataSubmitted = true;
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way? Apps like Whatsapp seem trying to send the data all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately no improvement. Might be the timeout too low?

Comment: I have found out that I sometimes get the HTTP Code 500 which implies a "Internal Server" error. Is there a way to solve it? I am using a normal webspace for a website.

Comment: It says their is Web Server error. Have a look at [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm). It will give you an idea.